# Use Microsoft DPM 2010 with Azure or Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, azure, scdpm

Does anyone know of any software that hooks up with Microsoft's DPM 2010 or even the new 2012 to ship data to cloud storage providers like Azure or S3?

We utilize D2D backups today but want a more robust off-site solution than using a virtual tape library to off-site disk backups.  I know there are providers through Iron Mountain but quite frankly the per GB storage price with Azure and S3 is far cheaper than anything Iron Mountain can or will provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of DPM 2012 SP1 DPM is able to upload to Azure.

Source and more info:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848299.aspx

Comment: This looks pretty damn promising. Thanks for posting!